# Nextjs with react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-leaflet

I'm create Nextjs app and use leaflet package for react (react-leaflet). I have geojson with boundaries for every country.

I need: 
On country hover - highlight this country with gray color 
On country mouseout - remove styles 
On country click (when is hovered) - change highlight color to green

Everything from this work but I need set state `selectedCountry` for working with clicked country in `mouseout` event.
On mouseout - reset styles only when is not clicked on this country (remove gray highlight). When is clicked to other country, state `selectedCountry` will be overwritten with other clicked country. 
I need send country to parent component using callback `getCountry` too.

There is problem, **when I uncomment lines for send callback and set state in `onCountryClick` function - it stop working properly.
For example, I must click 2times to country to set green highlight.**
I think it is some problem when states are changed? How can I fix it?
Feedback on the code is also welcome

This is my component (problem is commented in onCountryClick function)

```
'use client'

import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, GeoJSON, Layer , Feature} from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

import geoJsonData from '@/components/countries.geo.json'; //TODO remove and get from backend

type CountriesGeoJson = {
  type: string;
  features: {
    type: string;
    properties: {
      type: string;
      name: string;
      iso3: string;
      iso2: string;
    };
    geometry: {
      type: string;
      coordinates: number[][][];
    };
  }[];
}

type MapComponentProps = {
  className?: string;
  getCountry: (iso2: ISO2Code) => void;
};

const MapComponent: React.FC<MapComponentProps> = ({ className, getCountry }) => {
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState<ISO2Code | null>(null);
  const geoJsonRef = useRef<GeoJSON | null>(null);

  function getLayerByISO2(iso2: ISO2Code): Layer | null {
    const geoJsonLayers = geoJsonRef.current?._layers;

    if (!geoJsonLayers) {
      return null;
    }
  
    for (const layerId in geoJsonLayers) {
      const layer = geoJsonLayers[layerId];
  
      if (layer.feature && layer.feature.properties && layer.feature.properties.iso2 === iso2) {
        return layer;
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  function onCountryHover(event: any) {
    const layer: Layer = event.target;
    const feature: Feature = event.sourceTarget.feature;
    const iso2: ISO2Code = feature.properties.iso2;

    layer.setStyle({
      weight: 2,
      color: '#666',
    });

    console.log("HOVER: " + iso2);
  };

  function onCountryOut(event: any) {
    const layer: Layer = event.target;
    const feature: Feature = event.sourceTarget.feature;
    const iso2: ISO2Code = feature.properties.iso2;

    if (iso2 !== selectedCountry) {
      // Reset style only if it's not the selected country
      layer.setStyle({
        weight: 0,
      });
    }
  };

  function onCountryClick(event: any) {
    const layer: Layer = event.target;
    const feature: Feature = event.sourceTarget.feature;
    const iso2: ISO2Code = feature.properties.iso2;

    
    layer.setStyle({
      weight: 2,
      color: 'green',
    });
    
    //TODO - when uncomment - not working properly (styles is set on second click)
    // setSelectedCountry(iso2);
    // getCountry(iso2);
    console.log("CLICKED: " + iso2);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer style={{
        height: '100vh',
        width: '100vw'
      }}
      center={[51, 0.0]}
      zoom={1.75}
      minZoom={1.75}
      maxBounds={[[-90, -180], [90, 180]]}
      worldCopyJump={true}
      className={className || ''}
      >
        <GeoJSON style={{
            fillColor: "transparent",
            color: "transparent",
          }}
          ref={geoJsonRef}
          data={geoJsonData} 
          onEachFeature={(feature, layer) => {
            layer.on({
              mouseover: onCountryHover,
              mouseout: onCountryOut,
              click: onCountryClick
            });

            // layer.on('click', onCountryClick);
          }}
        />

        <TileLayer
          url="https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

Thank you